# Most particles that have ever been modeled

Tags: particle-physics

Two billiard balls collide. Consider the two balls only, how many particles are in that system?

Have particle systems of that size been modeled with each individual particle before?

What is the largest object ever been modeled with pure particle physics?

Comment: This is not the kind of question this website favors and besides it may be more relevant on scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: The terminology you are using is not physics terminology. Particle physics model is the standard model, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Modeland the physics the particles obey are quantum mechanics which has nothing to do with billiard balls. Classical scattering of 10^23 molecules per mole have been modeled with the ideal gas, thermodynamically and with statistical mechanics.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas .

Comment: I disagree with the above comments.  This is an interesting question because it relates to how Statistical Mechanics and the Standard Model can predict macroscopic Newtonian Mechanics.  Furthermore, a billiard ball is certainly not an ideal gas.

Comment: @mcFreid In the physics vocabulary scattering "billiard balls" means totally elastic scatterings, and yes, the ideal gas classically is modeled like tiny billiard balls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The biggest I know of is the [Bolshoi simulation](http://hipacc.ucsc.edu/Bolshoi/) of cosmological structure formation. This used 8 billion particles - more superlatives are available on their web site.

This is a classical simulation i.e. the particles behave classically. If you're asking about quantum mechanical simulations then the answer is rather variable. Fully *ab initio* calculations are only feasible for relatively small molecules. Larger scale calculations, like protein structure, use approximations that render the calculation partly quantum and partly classical. So the *largest size* answer will depend on what approximations you're willing to accept.

Comment: That's a seriously impressive simulation

Comment: [Millennium XXL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Run#Millennium_XXL) seems to be bigger with 300 billion particles.

Comment: @user23660: yes indeed. You should turn that into an answer.

Comment: Thanks. So the answer technically is "relatively small molecules"? How many particles is that? A dozen? A thousand? Lets say it were 300 billion particles, how close is that to a single billiard ball?

Answer (score 3):

From your comment to John's answer I see that you have a totally different vocabulary.

> Two billiard balls collide. Consider the two balls only, how many particles are in that system?

A physicist will solve the collision of two colliding billiard balls by using the momenta and energies and taking the center of mass of each ball as a point particle. Rotational dynamics of the balls will enter in a more detailed calculation, but it will always be "two particles".

Now each billiard ball is composed out of an enormous number of mollecules tied up with electromagnetic forces in a stable configuration. The number is of the order of 10^23 molecules each. Each molecule is composed of a multiple of these, electrons and nucleons, and each nucleon is composed of three quarks. So the number of elementary particles is enormous, but not necessary to explain the macroscopic behavior of the billiard balls, at the energies that billiard balls collide. The model of mass(containing all those particles) and the motions of the center of mass and at most the rotational behavior is sufficient.

> Have particle systems of that size been modeled with each individual particle before?

It is not necessary to know what the molecules are doing to predict the trajectory of these two billiard balls to great accuracy, so no, nobody undertakes futile  tasks.

> What is the largest object ever been modeled with pure particle physics?

The DNA molecule and now the nano particle studies deal with pure particle physics as it collectively impacts  into the macroscopic world.  I have not heard of scattering DNA molecules, and I doubt a model exists. Some form of scattering modeling must be necessary to get their collective interactions of nano particles so the number is the number of molecules in a [nano particle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanoparticle). They seem to be of the order of hundreds or thousands.